# The name 'myClassInstance' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors, include

Environment: c#.net VS 2010

Solution has the following two projects:

- A dll with several tested methods I've added.
- A test project

The only thing in the test project is a form with following code: (names changed for readability)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DLL_PROJECT; //Yes I remembered to include the dll project

namespace DLL_PROJECT_Test
{
public partial class frmTest : Form
{
    private Class_1 myClass_1; //this comes from the dll - no errors here
    private Class_2 myClass_2 = new Class_2(); // no errors here either

    public frmTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //TransparencyKey = BackColor;
        this.SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        myDebouncer = new Debouncer(this);
        this.SetDragging(true); //THIS EXTENSION COMES FROM THE DLL AND WORKS FINE
        this.RoundCorners(40, 80); //AS DOES THIS ONE
        myClass_2 = new Class_2();
        myClass_2.HoldStartEvent += new Class_2EventHandler(myClass_2_HoldStartEvent);
        myClass_2.DragStartEvent += new Class_2EventHandler(myClass_2_DragStartEvent);
    }

    private void myClass_2_DragStartEvent(Class_2 sender)
    {
        myClass_2("DragStart") += 1; //THE ONLY ERROR IS HERE AS FOLLOWS
//ERROR: "The name 'myClass_2' does not exist in the current context"
//     - Yes, the DLL is included
//     - Yes, the project is .Net 4 (not client profile)
//     - Yes xxx WRONG xxx, this exact syntax has been tested before on an instance of
//       this class, it's just a default parameter.
// xxx should be [] instead of () for the indexer in c#.  #VB_Fails
    }

    void myClass_2_HoldStartEvent(Class_2 sender)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If this is readable, i do not know what is unreadable?

Comment: Are you supposed to be creating a new Class_2 object twice like you are? Why are you invoking your object like it's a method? Is Class_2 a delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
myClass_2("DragStart") += 1;
```

... is using `myClass_2` as if it were either the name of a *method* or a delegate instance.

Did you actually mean to use the indexer? That would be:

```
myClass_2["DragStart"] += 1;
```

What does `"DragStart"` mean here? Is it actually a property name? Perhaps you want:

```
myClass_2.DragStart += 1;
```

I very much doubt that "this exact syntax has been tested before on an instance of this class".

Admittedly the error message doesn't make much sense in this case. I think it's *actually* more likely that you've got a typo in your real code - a typo which isn't propagated here because you've changed the names. If you could reproduce this in a short but *complete* program, it would make life a lot simpler.

Comment: Nailed it. I'm constantly having to do VB and C# because most of our other programmers are VB. I did in fact mean to use the indexer. Changing it to [] instead of () fixes it.